# Kotlin code to java conversion

Tags: java, kotlin

im new to kotlin and i confused what this code equivalent in Java. Heres the code

```
fun <T> retryCall(call: Observable<Response<T>>)
```

I tried convert it to java with kotlin tool and the result is this and i dont think this is the code im looking for

```
 void retryCall(@NotNull Observable var1);
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you only put `Observable` which is not the full type declared in the Kotlin code. So as a start, do this:

```
void retryCall(@NotNull Observable<Response<T>> var1);
```

But now you will get a compiler error about `T`. So we need to be sure this is a generic method like this:

```
<T> void retryCall(@NotNull Observable<Response<T>> var1);
```

Comment: it gives me warning invalid method declaration; return type required

Comment: `<T> void retryCall(@NotNull Observable<Response<T>> var1);` I didn't test it but this is how I think it should be.

Comment: @MohammadTabbara i think this is what i looking for dont know you can put <T> before void. Thank a lot mate